# User Interface inspiration for iPhone Apps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, usability

Does anyone have any suggestions for a site that potentially has some inspirational user interfaces for building my own iPhone Apps. It's straight forward to continually build out applications with the conventional UIKit widgets, but it does not set you apart from the competition. Some resources on how to build attractive interfaces is highly desired for inspiration. This is for someone with minimal Photoshop/Illustrator skills, but doesn't mind using sites such as iStockPhoto and working with custom views.

Answer (score 4):

Apple is historically well-known for the user interfaces of its products and programs written for them, but in recent years it has come under fire for seemingly allowing its Human Interface Guidelines (HIG) to lapse. Some of the best Mac and iPhone applications are actually those that deviate from the HIG, but not so much that usability (or acceptance into the App Store) is sacrificed (see [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_Generation)).

Examples of such innovative iPhone applications can be found in the iPhone [app](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/ada/index.html#showcase) and [web app](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/ada/index.html#wepapp) showcases of Apple Design Award winners. These apps have been judged by Apple itself to be creative, inspiring, and exemplary of the iPhone platform's potential as a mobile computing device.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your local best buy, game stop, or any other store with xbox360s, wiis and playstation 3s lying around.  Play every single demo on these machines and rate them solely on UI experience.  Triple A console games still lead the interface world in my opinion.  Soft synths are a close second and also often have beautiful UIs (as Chris Schreiner pointed out).  A quick trip through [logic](http://www.apple.com/logicstudio/instruments/) will give you a glimpse of apple's own work in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out this [article](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/29/favorites-ui-design) by Matt Gemmell about his process in designing the UI for his Favorites app.

Answer (score 2):

[10 Gorgeously Designed iPhone Applications](http://www.razorianfly.com/2009/10-gorgeously-designed-iphone-applications/) has some very nicely designed apps.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a long time getting this one together, it's a full list of every single ios inspiration / mobile css gallery I could find on the internet. Let me know if you find any others so I can add them!

http://www.kintek.com.au/web-design-blog/iphone-mobile-css-gallery-listing-ios-inspiration/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: My source of inspiration comes from the software-synth domain. Circle from FAW comes to mind. Ableton Live is (in my book) something to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a good [article](http://tapbots.com/blog/design/designing-convertbot) about designing the Convertbot application. A very simple app that stands out because of its UI.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to burst your bubble, but great design is not something you will get from finding a "site" to look at.  Major universities have graduate design programs, that's the kind of place where some people learn to be great designers.  Multiple courses and textbooks on design and all the related areas (art, architecture, psychology, biomechanics, etc., etc.)  I've seen too many engineers, without at least some of this training, routinely suggest some really bad UI design ideas.  Don't be another one of them.

Treat learning great design as something far bigger than finding a site (or learning another programming language, etc.), more like a multi-year endeavor, and you might have a chance.

Or find and team up with someone who's already an experienced designer.